# How MongoDB Performs when using LINQ .Contains Operator

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

From MongoDB driver for LINQ. Is there any harm in using .Contains for searching inside a field of collection?

> When do we have to go for Regex lookup for predictive searches?

[Ref: Official Doc](https://mongodb-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver.html)

> Contains (Enumerable method)
>
> This method is used to test whether an array (or array-like) field or
>   property contains a particular value:
>
> var query =
>       from c in collection.AsQueryable()
>       where c.A.Contains(123)
>       select c; // or var query =
>       collection.AsQueryable()
>       .Where(c => c.A.Contains(123)); This is translated to the following MongoDB query:

Comment: It will have to scan the collection. If you're already limiting with something else (like _id) to ensure you get a small collection, it's probably fine. It's probably best if you test any query you write with an `explain` to see how it will perform.

Comment: thanks @john, +1 unfortunately not limiting the queries by any id. thanks for `explain` pointers. Seems Regex is the only way to going forward!